# What is the difference between these two map expressions in Scala/Python?

Tags: python, scala, mapreduce, bigdata, apache-spark

Is there any difference between the two?

```
1. a = b.map(lambda (x,y): (y,x))
2. a = b.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

For those who work in Scala, I think it would be something like this.

```
1. a = b.map((x,y) => (y,x))
2. a = b.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2 those are identical.

The difference in Python 3 is that the first one is a syntax error and the second one isn't.

The difference in Scala is that the first one is a binary function and the second one is a unary function taking a tuple. If you want to pattern match you have to pass a partial function, like this: `y.map{ case (x,y) => (y,x) }`.

Comment: but this: 'List(1 -> 10, 2 -> 20).map((a, b) => (b, a))' doesn't compile in scala - or did i miss something?

Comment: @j-keck Of course it doesn't. `map` takes a unary function and you're passing a binary function.

Comment: yes - so the first one is a syntax error in scala too (like in python3)